# OOP in conjunction with any API/SQL

Tags: php, sql, oop

Currently I am combining two APIs and as I have done in former such projects, I create a 1-1 relation between the SQL Table rows and fields in an object.

But I am unsure how to get around it when dealing with an API that takes some information of an item and from this information provides new information that's attached to that very item.

Example in PHP:

```
class Cart {
    public $cartItems, $reference;

    public function __construct(array $cartItems, string $reference) {
        $this->cartItems = $cartItems;
        $this->reference = $reference;
    }
}
```

Say an API (Alike [Imaterialize](https://i.materialise.com/api/demo/cart-creation-api.htm)) took a *json_encoded* version of this and would return a *cart_id*.

**Question**: What would be the best approach at this point? - Should one add an extra field to the *Cart* class or would one create another class that extended *Cart* with this extra field?

If *Cart* had an extra field that would get initialized only after the information was available, then how would one go about differentiating a *Cart* that had the ID and one that had not? - Sure one could create a boolean or any sort of function to keep track of it.

I find it hard to get my head around, but my best guess would be that what I am searching is a Design Pattern for this kind of interaction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Exfidos Check out [this article](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Dependency-Injection-in-PHP-example-how-to-DI-create-your-own-dependency-injection-container) on dependency injection and design patterns, it helped me out in a similar situation to yours.

Comment: @AkinWilliams Thanks for your response! I've read the article, but I am not entirely sure how DI would become beneficial in this particular case. Could I not just use the same constructor with variable arguments; creating the cart either with or without the ID?
Perhaps I did not explain myself properly: I create a Cart object in PHP -> Create the cart at the API using this Cart Information -> Gets a CartID response from the API. Then here I would like to know a proper way of managing the data. Hope I make sense :)

Comment: Is combining this API refactoring or a feature for your project? In other words, is there still any use in split API?

Comment: @RoboRobok The project consists of taking information from one API, slightly altering it based on preferences stored in a Database (So the PHP acts as a "middleman") and then sending the information to the last API (which is where my main question arises on how it should be handled).

Comment: Then I think it's nice to mirror this fact in your code, to avoid confusion in the future. Having one-to-one relationships reflected in models is perfectly fine.

Comment: @RoboRobok I've done this in all past projects as it works out great, but say you have a customer object in php. You want to put this into a database, so before that is done you could not possibly have a Auto Generated ID row yet. But if I then wanna keep working with this specific Customer object in conjunction with the auto generated key that will be returned after creating the Customer, how would one go about storing the information in a more meaningful way?

Comment: I don't quite understand your concern here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118112/discussion-between-exfridos-and-robo-robok).